# How to increment an input name by cloning?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html form with some inputs type=text. I can clone every input but I would like to recover the name to insert informations in my database. Therefore, I have to increment all the name. I can increment only one type of input and not multiple.

```
    <body>

        <button id="clone">Cloner</button>
        <button id="removebutton">Remove</button>


        <form id="myForm">

            <div class="equipment" id="eqp">
                    <h4 class="title4">EQUIPEMENT 1 / EQUIPMENT 1</h4>
                        <label>Date de prêt / Loan date:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="loandate" id="datepicker" placeholder="ex: 20170101"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Nom du produit / Product Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="productname" placeholder="ex: Asus"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Type:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="type"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Numéro de série / Serial Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="serialnumber" placeholder="ex: A003565DS65"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Statuts / Status:</label>
                        <select name="status">
                            <option>gg</option>
                            <option>hh</option>
                        </select><br/><br/>             
            </div>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#clone').click(function () {

    $('#myForm').append($('#eqp:last').clone());
    $('#myForm div').each(function (i) {
        var textinput1 = $(this).find('input');
        var textinput2 = $(this).find('input[text="productname"]');

        var select = $(this).find('select');

        i++;
        textinput1.eq(0).attr('name', 'loandate' + i);
        select.eq(0).attr('name', 'status' + i);
    });

});

$("#removebutton").click(function() {
    if ($('.equipment').length > 1)
        $('.equipment:last').remove()
});
//});
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input name="loandate[]" >`

You won't need to increment name, you will get the result as Array

Here's what you need to change into your HTML and JS:

```js
$('#clone').click(function () {

    $('#myForm').append($('.equipment:last').clone());
    $('#myForm div').each(function (i) {
       
    });

});

$("#removebutton").click(function() {
    if ($('.equipment').length > 1)
        $('.equipment:last').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button id="clone">Cloner</button>
        <button id="removebutton">Remove</button>


        <form id="myForm">

            <div class="equipment">
                    <h4 class="title4">EQUIPEMENT 1 / EQUIPMENT 1</h4>
                        <label>Date de prêt / Loan date:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="loandate[]" id="datepicker" placeholder="ex: 20170101"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Nom du produit / Product Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="productname[]" placeholder="ex: Asus"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Type:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="type[]"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Numéro de série / Serial Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="serialnumber[]" placeholder="ex: A003565DS65"/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Statuts / Status:</label>
                        <select name="status[]">
                            <option>gg</option>
                            <option>hh</option>
                        </select><br/><br/>             
            </div>

        </form>
```

Consider that you had error into your html. Equipment div element has an ID (`#eqp`). After cloning that div you're getting multiple elements with the same ID. (That's not good).

What you need to change is:

- Remove that ID and use class selector
- Edit form names like this: `name[]`
- Simplify your JS. No need to set different names for each element
- Into your PHP manipluate with them as an array.

PHP Example:

```
$i = 0;

do{

    $loandate = $_POST['loandate'][$i];
    $type = $_POST['type'][$i]
    //...

    $i++;

}while(isset($_POST['loandate'][$i]))
```

Comment: But I can not recover the name in PHP no? So I just have to do a "for" to recover all?

Comment: from PHP you can refer as `$_POST['loandate']`. It will give you an array and you will iterate through like `$_POST['loandate'][0]`

Comment: Something like this ?: 
for{
      $loandate = $_POST['loandate'][0];
}

Comment: In my wamp the clone doesn't work I don't know why. When I run your code here it works. I don't understand

Comment: If this works, i'd like to see it marked as "Correct Answer", and if you have any other problems you can open new Question about that.

Comment: So if i understand, I can use as an array and read it with a foreach ? I don't know how exactly I have to do that in php.